# i have a stored procedure is showing below that takes to much time to give the output

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I am facing this error:

> Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

I have a stored procedure is showing below that takes to much time to give the output

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[Psectionauthorizationlistidandsemsterwise] 
--pSectionAuthorizationListIdandSemsterWise 10104,3 
@EmpCode  INT, 
@Semester INT 
AS 
BEGIN 
  SET nocount ON; 

  DECLARE @CurrentSession VARCHAR(6)=(SELECT dbo.Getcurrentsession()) 
  DECLARE @NextSession VARCHAR(6)=(SELECT dbo.Getnextsession()) 

  SELECT DISTINCT a.*, 
                  (SELECT programname + ':' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, programid) 
                          + ',' 
                   FROM   programs 
                   WHERE  programid IN (SELECT DISTINCT programid 
                                        FROM   vstudentcourseregistration 
                                        WHERE  coursecode = a.coursecode 
                                               AND section = a.section 
                                               AND 
                                       studentgroup = a.studentgroup) 
                   FOR xml path(''))     AS Program, 
                  Isnull(SSA.empcode, 0) AS EmpCode 
  FROM   (SELECT DISTINCT CR.coursecode, 
                          coursename, 
                          Cr.section, 
                          CR.studentgroup, 
                          programid, 
                          Max(CR.semester) AS Semester, 
                          coursetype 
          FROM   vstudentcourseregistration CR, 
                 courseareamaster ca 
          WHERE  ca.coursearea = LEFT(Cr.coursecode, Len(coursearea)) 
                 AND semester = @Semester 
                 AND CR.isactive = 1 
                 AND ca.authlogin = @EmpCode 
                 AND cr.session = @NextSession 
          GROUP  BY CR.coursecode, 
                    coursename, 
                    CR.section, 
                    CR.studentgroup, 
                    coursetype, 
                    programid) AS a 
         LEFT OUTER JOIN staffsectionauthorization SSA 
                      ON a.coursecode = SSA.coursecode 
                         AND Isnull(a.section, '') = SSA.section 
                         AND a.studentgroup = SSA.studentgroup 
                         AND SSA.session = @NextSession 
                         AND SSA.isactive = 1 
                         AND a.semester = SSA.semester 
 END
```

Comment: Too many joins and usage of "xml path" mean that without an attached plan or at least any hints regarding the indexing of the used tables we cannot provide any concrete solution

Comment: So increase the timeout you are setting for your `SqlCommand`.